# HTML5 input pattern require first character must be a forward slash

Tags: html, validation

I need to require a forward slash to be the first character without exception for an HTML5 input pattern attribute. Here are some examples of what I've attempted:

```
pattern="^[/].+{1,128}"
pattern="^[\/].+{1,128}"
pattern="^/.+{1,128}"
pattern="^\/.+{1,128}"
```

Unfortunately what I've tried allows alphanumeric and other characters as the first character. I also can't recall if it's the forward or back slash that requires escaping. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last option should be OK, if you remove the plus sign

This should match anything starting by slash, followed by 1 to 128 chars (any characters)

```
pattern="^\/.{1,128}"
```

Comment: Close enough! Thank you! Turns out I was looking for `^\/.{0,127}`.